# Run duplicate version of app

Tags: macos

I need to run duplicate versions of an app on mac os but every time I do it it auto closes. I tried duplicating the .app file but it doesn't work, do I need to create another account and switch between users to run the same app twice?.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details. Like what app are you trying to run...

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-open-multiple-instances-of-an-application-in-os-x/ ? "open -n" seems to be th key.

Comment: It is not always possible. If the application is designed to not allow multiple instances of it to run simultaneously then any subsequent instance exits, no matter what options you pass to `open`.